# ¿Cómo aplicar correctamente la recursividad en php?

Tags: php, arraylist, recursión

Estoy trabajando en php, tengo un array de objetos que tiene nombre, precio y marca; al momento de realizar la suma de los precios deseo utilizar recursividad, pero cuando ejecuto la método que suma los precios esto se vuelve infinito, ya intente varias cosas pero no encuentro la solución correcta. La función que estoy utilizando es:

```
function getPrice(){  

    $products = $this ->list_products;

    $price = 0; 

    foreach( $products as $product){
        if( $product )
            echo ' valor de precio '.  $product  -> price .'<br>';  
            $price = $product  -> price +  $this -> getPrice();
    }

    return $price ; 

}
```

Alguno de ustedes me podría ayudar, ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo así, sin tener que recorrer el array: `$products = $this ->list_products; $price=array_sum(array_column($products,"price")); return $price;` En cuanto a la forma que estás implementando me parece muy extraña. Si `getPrice` es un método de la clase y `$product` es una instancia de esa misma clase no sé por qué quieres hacer una especie de llamada recursiva ahí ¿?  ¿por qué una instancia de la clase tendría que tener potestad sobre otras instancias? A lo sumo, la clase podría tener otro método llamado más o menos `getTotalPrices` al cual pasas un array de instancias y suma precios

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, para el caso que expones no necesitas recursividad solo recorre el Array de objetos y suma sus propiedades precio. Ejemplo:

```
function getPrice(){  
     // Recuperamos el Array de objetos
    $products = $this ->list_products;
    // variable para acumular la suma
    $total = 0; 
    // recorremos el array
    foreach( $products as $product){
            //echo ' valor de precio '.  $product  -> price .'<br>'; 
            // acumulamos la suma 
            $total += $product->price;
    }
    // retornamos la suma
    return $total ; 
}
```

Sí estamos trabajando con PHP>=7.0 podemos utilizar la sugerencia de A.Cedano, ya que hasta PHP7.0 array_column no permite trabajar con Array de objetos:

```
function getPrice(){  
    $products = $this ->list_products;
    $total = array_sum(array_column($products, "price"));
    return $total;
}
```